# Complex integral verification

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

[image]

Z = 4 is not in the circle |z| = 2 so that integral to 0, correct?

Comment: z=4 is not a pole of |z|=2 so that integral does not "add" anything

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting $g(z) = \dfrac{z}{(z-4)(z+1)}$ then $g(z)$ has one pole at $z=-1$ in the contour $|z|=2$. By Cauchy's integral formula $$ \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz =f(a)2\pi i,  $$ we let $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{z-4}$ and note $a=-1$ hence $$\oint_{|z|=2} g(z)dz = \dfrac{-1}{-1-4}2\pi i =  \dfrac{2\pi i}{5}.$$